# .NET - подмена кода в рантайме

Tags: c#, .net, clr, code-injection

Добрый день. Имеется класс из .NET BCL, назовем его `SomeClass` со свойством `SomeProperty`:

```
// namespace System.XXX
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get { ... } }
}
```

Также имеется сторонняя библиотека `SomeLibrary`, методы которой принимают в качестве аргумента объекты этого класса:

```
public class SomeLibraryClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(SomeClass arg)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Очень хотелось бы изменить поведение `SomeProperty`. Можно было бы создать наследника `SomeClass` и переопределить свойство, однако, оно не отмечено как `virtual`. Соответственно, сторонняя библиотека не сможет работать с новым свойством, всегда будет использоваться свойство базового класса.

Необходимо, **не изменяя** `SomeLibrary` обеспечить иное поведение `SomeProperty`. Есть ли решения проще, чем описанные, например, [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time)? Глобальное изменение поведения `SomeProperty` (не только в контексте `SomeLibrary`) приемлемо.

Comment: Поменять значение свойства нельзя что ли? Как ещё вы хотите поменять поведение свойства?

Comment: @Monk Свойство get-only, с довольно сложной логикой.

Comment: Можно попытаться сделать это через [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net)

Answer (score 4):

Придумал следующий велосипед. Формально требование о неизменности библиотеки соблюдается - на диске всегда оригинальный файл. Однако, по факту она модифицируется в памяти:

1. Написал программу, которая при помощи [`Mono.Cecil`](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) проходится по всем методам у всех типов в `SomeLibrary`. Если метод содержит аргументы типа `SomeClass`, он заменяется на тип моей реализации `SomeClass` с перекрытым свойством. Затем идет проход по IL-инструкциям тела метода, ищуются инструкции виртуального вызова исходного свойства и подменяются вызовами модифицированного свойства. Измененная сборка сохраняется на диск.
2. В проект вместо `SomeLibrary` добавил в зависимости эту фейковую библиотеку, копирование ее при компиляции отключил.
3. `SomeLibrary` положил в подкаталог, написал обработчик `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`, который читает библиотеку из подкаталога и повторяет над ней действия из п.1, только теперь фейк не сохраняется на диск, а грузится сразу из памяти через `Assembly.Load`.